# Python: How to add module from sibling folder

Tags: python, visual-studio, module, package, python-import

I have the following folder structure for my Python Project:

```
pythonApp             --> Folder
|--ABC                --> Package
   |--__init__.py     --> Empty File
   |--abctest.py      --> Module
|--DEF                --> Package
   |--__init__.py     --> Empty File
   |--deftest.py      --> Module
|--Common             --> Package
   |--__init__.py     --> Empty File
   |--constants.py    --> Module
```

I want to import `constants.py`under the `Common` package in the `abctest.py`. Using `from Common import constants` throws error `Module not found`. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` at the `pythonApp` root?

Comment: @GarrettKadillak: Yes, inside the pythonApp root , I do have the __init__.py file

Answer (score 1):

in `abctest.py`, add the parent directory to python path using `__file__` as current module name, then take the dirname of the dirname to compute it:

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

from Common import constants
```

note: python 2 seems to need a `__init__.py` file (even empty) in `Common` directory to be able to recognize `Common` as a module, whereas python 3 can do without.

Comment: Fabre: What I did is I created a run.py directly under pythonApp folder. I set run.py as start up file. And included the following code: `import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path[0] + '\ABC')`. It works fine on local. But when I create a executable, it crashes.

Comment: can you show us how you create your executable (maybe edit your question to include that part)